Is it weird that my probability theory lecturer thinks that $P(E)=0$ implies that $E=\emptyset$?
I'm an undergraduate student in pure mathematics, and I'm taking a probability theory course based on the book A First Course in Probability by Sheldon Ross. My lecturer defined the conditional probability $P(A|B)$ of two events $A,B$ by $P(A|B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$, provided that $B\neq\emptyset$. I knew that $P(\emptyset)=0$, and after some research, I realized that the converse is not true, namely, from $P(E)=0$ we can't conclude that $E=\emptyset$. I wrote to my lecturer, and among other things, I gave him a simple counterexample. (First I asked him to prove his claim, but instead he "proved" to me that $P(\emptyset)=0$, but he relied on $P(E^c)+P(E)=1$ which was proved in the book by "the finite version" of Axiom 3, which was proved using Axiom 3 and the fact that $P(\emptyset)=0$.) The simple counterexample was the sample space $S=\{1,2\}$ together with the function $P$ defined by $P(\{1\})=0,P(\{2\})=1,P(\{1,2\})=1,P(\emptyset)=0$, it's a simple matter to verify that $P$ satisfies the three axioms of probability, yet $P(\{1\})=0$ and $\{1\}\neq\emptyset$. Yet he went in circles claiming that every sample point in the sample space (i.e., a singleton subset of the sample space) needs to have positive probability—which is of course nonsense. I was getting the feeling that he doesn't like rigour, and on further researching, I found out that his background is in engineering and applied statistics. Is it normal that he has this false belief (I mean normal for people who are more interested in applied probability rather than rigorous mathematics)?

Yes, it is weird, because this is blatantly false.

Even if not “weird” it is VERY disheartening.

Unless you absolutely must take this class at this time, I would drop it and take it again with a better teacher.

Alternative example : If you pick a real number $~x,~$ at random, where you are required to have $~0 < x < 1,~$ what is the probability that the number selected is $~x = 1/2.$

It's not a bad exercise to supply the rigor on your own, as it seems you have been doing.  Yeah, there's some danger that you'll miss a gap or two, but, on the other hand, you'll strengthen the paranoid instinct you really need for this stuff.

I would not be too sure about what the lecturer knows or doesn't know. Your book does no continuous distributions until chapter 5, page 186 in the 8th edition; it seems unlikely that either one of you understood what the other was talking about.

From what you describe, it seems like the focus in your course might be on discrete distributions. You could argue that non-empty events with zero probability are only interesting in the context of continuous distributions. For discrete distributions, you can replace a probability space $(\Omega, 2^{\Omega}, P)$ ($\Omega$ countable) with $(\Omega^{*}, 2^{\Omega^{*}}, P|_{2^{\Omega^{*}}})$ where $\Omega^{*} = \{\omega \in \Omega:P(\omega)>0\}$ and model basically the exact same situation.
The downside of this is that this restricted probability space $\Omega^{*}$ can often be unnatural because it depends on $P$. You might have different $\Omega^{*}$'s for different measures. You also might not know a priori for which $\omega$ that $P(\omega)=0$ which is an issue.
But your lecturer just strikes me as confused. The engineering degree isn't an excuse since engineers usually know about continuous distributions, and in such distributions certainly it's both possible and meaningful that $P(E)=0$ for non-empty events $E$.

In your last paragraph, my take is that the student's description of the lecturer's shortcomings is not believable; the lecturer was focusing  on the discrete world they are doing for now, until chapter 5, while the student jumps ahead. The student is, as we often see on MSE, very quick to assign blame to others for seeming errors. They need a marriage counselor.

@WillJagy In chapter 2, there is no limitation on the cardinality of the sample space. Also, the counterexample which I gave in the question is discrete (the sample space has exactly two elements).
